# Access violation writing location 0x00000000

Tags: c++, directx, direct3d

When the application reaches these lines of code:

```
ID3D11ShaderResourceView* tempMeshSRV;
wstring MediaFilePath = DefaultPath + fileNamePath;
hr = D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile( d3d11Device, MediaFilePath.c_str(), NULL, NULL, &tempMeshSRV, NULL );
```

I get the following error:

Unhandled exception at 0x011428b5 in Game.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.

It was working fine until I added the "wstring MediaFilePath = DefaultPath + fileNamePath;" line. The resource it is trying to load is definitely in the correct location.

Comment: Debug it, what is the value of `DefaultPath` and `fileNamePath`, and what are their types ?

Comment: You have a null pointer.  Use the debugger to see where it is (I am assuming that `tempMeshSRV` is assigned in `D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile` as you are passing in its address.)

Comment: The `DefaultPath` object is set to "Content/Models/" and the `fileNamePath` is "face.jpg" making "Content/Models/face.jpg" which is the correct location the image file is currently located. Yes Ed, `tempMeshSRV` is set in the `D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile`. It is not returning null though which is why I am little confused.

Comment: Do you have the correct access rights to read/write from/to this location?

Comment: Yes I do, it's quite strange but I bet I am missing something simple... :/

Comment: I have just found the solution. The HRESULT object `hr` was causing the error. Removing it stopped the crashing. I then just added a new instance of it there and then like so:

`HRESULT hr = D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile( d3d11Device, MediaFilePath.c_str(), NULL, NULL, &tempMeshSRV, NULL );`

Comment: I doubt that was the reason. Assigning HRESULT value does nothing with pointers. I'd suggest you had bad `d3d11Device`, when you somehow fixed device creation the problem gone.

Answer (score 0):

Do DefaultPath and fileNamePath have type "wstring" or "const wchar_t*"?  If they're "const wchar_t*", then adding them won't do what you want it to.  (It'll add the two pointer values).

Comment: Both `DefaultPath` & `fileNamePath` are of type std::wstring